# how to match a letter in words then color it in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want an if conditional to match for a letter inside a sentence and color every match letters with red color.

```
<style type="text/css">
.clr1{ color:#FF0000; }
</style>
<script>
var str ='Hello World';
var chars=str.split("");
var result ='';
for (var i=0;i<chars.length;i++){
    // what should I write here?
      }
}
document.write('<h1>'+result+'</h1>');
</script>
```

Comment: This smells like homework, which is absolutely fine, but it shows no actual effort from you and only asks us to give you a copy&paste answer... All you need is already in your question. You will need an `if` which compares the current character with something and you will have to wrap the letter (which requires string concatenation) in something that can have a css class which doesn't break the flow of the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply wrap the letter within a span if the condition is true:

```js
var str = 'Hello World';
var chars = str.split("");
var result = '';
for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
  if(chars[i]=='l')
    result+='<span class="clr1">'+chars[i]+'</span>';
  else
    result+=chars[i];
}

document.write('<h1>' + result + '</h1>');
```

```css
.clr1 {
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

Comment: if(chars[i]=='i'||'o')
I tried to add or condition but it colored all sentence

Comment: @akrammalek it's should be `if(chars[i]=='i' || chars[i]=='o')`

Comment: I tried to use it in Arabic language string but it didn't work.

Comment: <style type="text/css">
.clr1{ color:#FF0000; }
.clr2{ color:#0000FF; }
</style>
<script>
var str ='|2|ٱلْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ رَبِّ ٱلْعَٰلَمِينَ';
var chars=str.split("");
var result ='';
for (var i=0;i<chars.length;i++){

if(chars[i]=='رَ'||chars[i]=='عَٰ'){
  result+='<span class="clr2">'+chars[i]+'</span>';
   }
  else{
    result+=chars[i];
   }
}
document.write('<h1>'+result+'</h1>');
</script>

Comment: @akrammalek Ok I see, you are making things for the Koran ;) ... well, I think it won't be easy for those letter, They are not handled like English one because the ponctuation is also considered. For example : `عَٰ` is 2 letter `ع َ ٰ`. So I think you should find a kind of library that deals with arabic letters or you will get crazy with all the different cases

Comment: FYI, I'm working on project to color some letter in Quran based on Tajweed grammar, so do you think javascript will handle it. because there are a lot conditions statements

Comment: @akrammalek it can but writing native code will be a pain, I think you should find a kind of library that handle Arabic letter. it's not easy at all to write conditions for all the differente cases

Comment: what is wrong with this code   char[2]=char[2].replace(char[2][start],'<span class="clr2 ">'+char[2][start]+'</span>');

Answer (score -1):

Simple JavaScript ( Highlighted letter is "o" )

```js
var str ="Hello World";
var chars=str.split("");
var result ="";
for (var i=0;i<chars.length;i++){
    if(chars[i] == "o"){ result+="<span>"+chars[i]+"</span>"; } else { result+=chars[i]; }
}
document.write("<h1>"+result+"</h1>");
```

```css
span  { color:#FF0000; }
```

I have used span tags because they do not break line like div (without display: inline-block).

Comment: Is there something wrong with this? plz help me understand

Comment: I guess it was downvoted because this is an almost exact copy of another answer that was posted long before it.

Comment: But thats the easiest way and i wrote it originally. If i change the code it becomes longer. This was the shortest way

Comment: I think i made it even shorter

Comment: thank you bro, it worked. but I tried to use this code with Arabic string yet it didn't work. do you know why

Comment: <style type="text/css"> .clr1{ color:#FF0000; } .clr2{ color:#0000FF; } </style> <script> var str ='|2|ٱلْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ رَبِّ ٱلْعَٰلَمِينَ'; var chars=str.split(""); var result =''; for (var i=0;i<chars.length;i++){ if(chars[i]=='رَ'||chars[i]=='عَٰ'){ result+='<span class="clr2">'+chars[i]+'</span>'; } else{ result+=chars[i]; } } document.write('<h1>'+result+'</h1>'); </script>

Comment: @akram malek there's no problem with that code but since i don't speak arabic, you can debug it by printing the chars array.